# Using pjax with salvattore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

I'm using pjax and salvattore in my blog, but whenever I click a link, salvattore doesn't work anymore. I have this code:

```
$(document)
 .pjax ('#navigation a', '#wrap', {fragment:'#wrap', timeout:650})
 .on('pjax:complete', function(){
   $('.content').attr('data-columns',1);
   $('#entry').addClass('column size-1of2');
});
```

but `pjax:complete` just makes pjax do a full page reload. Can someone help out? Thanks!

EDIT:
`timeout:650` was causing the full page reload, so I changed that to 0. But still, salvattore is not working.